# Over saturation in RAW files

Tags: photoshop

I have a canon 7D and shot some images in RAW which came out on the camera and JPEG as I wanted them to. When I open the RAW file in Photoshop CC the images lose definition and become totally over saturated. I have changed the colour settings but no difference is made. I have a deadline to meet on Monday for editing and I need help?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the RAW file in most RAW convertors it will apply the default settings you have instructed the convertor to use (or the convertor's default settings if you haven't set any yourself). The preview pictures you see on the camera's LCD and the JPEGS produced in-camera apply the in-camera settings to the RAW data.

If you want to open the RAW files on your computer using the in-camera settings to render the RAW file on your monitor, open the RAW files using Canon's *Digital Photo Professional (DPP)*. DPP will apply the in-camera settings to each image by default until you change them. Please note that regardless of what application you use to open a RAW file, what you see on your monitor is not the RAW file itself, but a conversion of that file into an 8-bit per color channel format (much like the JPEG standard) that your monitor can display.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the color settings in camera? RAW images are just the raw data that comes from the sensor before it goes through the on-camera image processing. You'll naturally need to change some settings before your RAW files start looking like your JPEGs.

Comment: @Shaz: Please remember to vote up any good answers, and accept the one that solves your problem.